# scheme for n-dimensional induction

Tags: induction

In slides:
http://www.mathdb.org/notes_download/elementary/algebra/ae_A2.pdf
I read the scheme for 2-dimensional induction, but Exists an scheme for n-dimensional induction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this slides we can construct $k$-dimensional scheme this way:

> Let $S(n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_k)$ denote a statement involving $k$
>   variables $n_1,n_2, \cdots, n_k$. Suppose:
>
> (i) $S(1,1,\cdots, 1)$ is true.
>
> (ii) $S(1,n_2, \cdots, n_k)$ is true for all positive integers
>   $n_2,\cdots, n_k$.
>
> (iii) If $S(n_1,n_2,\cdots, n_k)$ holds for some positive
>   $n_1,n_2,\cdots, n_k$, then $S(n_1+1,n_2, \cdots, n_k)$ is also true.
>
> Then $S(n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_k)$ is true for all positive integers
>   $n_1,n_2, \cdots, n_k$.

Note that sometimes you can prove (ii) using $(k-1)$-dimensional induction putting $T(n_2,\cdots, n_k)=S(1,n_2,\cdots, n_k)$ and prove that $T$ is true for all positive integers by induction(it's an idea in $2$-dimensional scheme).

Comment: iii) is $\exists n_1,n_2,....,n_k \in \Bbb{N}(S(n_1,n_2,\cdots, n_k) \Rightarrow S(n_1+1,n_2, \cdots, n_k))$!?

Comment: No, (iii) is $\forall n_1,n_2,\cdots, n_k(S(n_1,n_2,\cdots, n_k) \Rightarrow S(n_1+1,n_2,\cdots,n_k))$.

Comment: I am thinking, Can I use the following scheme:
$$\text{if}$$$$S(1,1,\cdots, 1)$$$$\forall n_1,n_2,\cdots, n_k(S(n_1,n_2,\cdots, n_k) \Rightarrow S(n_1+1,n_2,\cdots,n_k))$$$$\forall n_1,n_2,\cdots, n_k(S(n_1,n_2,\cdots, n_k) \Rightarrow S(n_1,n_2+1,\cdots,n_k))$$$$\cdots \cdots \cdots$$$$\forall n_1,n_2,\cdots, n_k(S(n_1,n_2,\cdots, n_k) \Rightarrow S(n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_k+1))$$$$\text{then}$$$$\forall n_1,n_2,\cdots, n_k(S(n_1,n_2,\cdots, n_k))$$ ??? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Yes, you can. Note that using first line and $s(1,1,\cdots,1)$ you can prove that $S(n,1,1,\cdots,1)$ for all $n$, using second you and $S(n,1,1,\cdots,1)$ you can prove $S(n,m,1,1,\cdots,1)$ for all $n,m$ and in the same way you get $S(n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_k)$.