# Prove: $a^m\cdot a^n \cdot a^p=a^{m+n+p}$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification, induction

How can I prove the following:

***Prop.***: let be $m,n,p \in \Bbb{N}$ and $a \in \Bbb{R}$ then $$a^m\cdot a^n \cdot a^p=a^{m+n+p}$$
???  I thinked by induction and I must prove:

**1)** $a^0\cdot a^0 \cdot a^0=a^{0+0+0}$ is true

**2)** $a^m\cdot a^n \cdot a^p=a^{m+n+p} \Rightarrow a^{m+1}\cdot a^n \cdot a^p=a^{m+1n+p}$ is true

**3)** $a^m\cdot a^n \cdot a^p=a^{m+n+p} \Rightarrow a^{m}\cdot a^{n+1} \cdot a^p=a^{m+n+1+p}$ is true

**4)** $a^m\cdot a^n \cdot a^p=a^{m+n+p} \Rightarrow a^{m}\cdot a^{n} \cdot a^{p+1}=a^{m+n+p+1}$ is true

If **1)**,**2)**,**3)**,**4)** are true then ***Prop***. is true

Is it correct?

Comment: Can you use the property $a^{mb}=a^m\cdot a^b$? Because then you can easily prove that property if you set $b=n+p$.

Comment: @Hakin, No I can't... It is a particular exercise!

Comment: What about logarithms?

Comment: You might encode the three integers into a single one, and perform induction over the encoded number. The induction step might be tricky, though.

Comment: @Hakim, I must to use induction...

Comment: Prove Hakim's property first by induction (note that $m, n\in \mathbb{N}$ which helps). Then your answer follows by using it twice.

Comment: @Kevin, Haki,, ok and it is true (thanks for hint :) )... but for curiosity, Can I use the http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856602/scheme-for-n-dimensional-induction or not?

Comment: You can, but it'll be really unpleasant.